# Entity Framework is connected architecture or disconnected architecture?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, architecture

I want to know if Entity Framework should be used in a connected or disconnected architecture?

Specially, I want to know how I can use EF in a layered architecture. For example how can I use it in ASP.NET code behind?

*NOTE: There are requests for closing this question as "Primarily opinion-based" and this is clearly not the case: EF can be used in both kind of scenaraios in a very specific way. That's not an opinion, but a clear fact. Noone can discuss it, or agree or disagree. If the question was about how to implement a disconnected scenario, then it would become "opinion-based", but not as is stated right now.*

Comment: May i know why i am upvoted ? Please give me reason for that

Comment: Actually you were downvoted. If you want to know the reason please read this: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Yes but i dont know why i am downvoted.

Comment: You can read it up in the link I posted. But actually you were downvoted because of several reasons. Your quetion is not really clear. You also do not provide any of your own effort on researching the topic...

Comment: @Käsebrot, with all my respect, you shouldn't be so dogmatic. There are many "not code-centric" questions that can be answered without incurring in the `too broad` or `unclerar what you asking` or `primarily opinion based` whichever other reason to downvote and close it. I think this is one of this cases. I mark may questions for closing, but I think this one doesn't deserve it. If you don't undertsnad the question, or any other thing, it's much better to help the OP clarify it.

Comment: Just to be clear pal, I did not downvote your question.

Answer (score 2):

You can use EF in both scenarios.

In a connected scenario, you can keep an instance of `DbContext` while you make changes to the entities (add, delete, update, modify), so that it tracks the cahnges and automatically send them to the database when calling `SaveChanges`.

In a disconnected scenario, for example a web application, you're responsible of tracking the changes. When you get the data back to the server you need to instance a new `DbContext`, attach the entities to it, set the state of each entity (new, deleted, modified), and call `SaveChanges`. For more information you can read [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/data/jj592676).

So, EF supports both scenarios, but in a different way.

Comment: Which is better? I guess the former in your discussion.

Comment: There is no best option. They are simply different. In the case of disconnected applications, like a web app, you have no choice. In a desktop application you can choose one of the two options. This question is like asking, which is better travelling by train or by bus?